distribution of square roots of unity $mod n$ | Factoring with inverse pair
I am writing a proof related to the RSA cryptosystem, specifically showing that given an inverse pair $d, c$ under multiplication mod $\phi(N)$, where
$$ dc \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(N)}, $$
there exists a probabilistic polynomial time algorithm that can factor $N = pq$, with $p$ and $q$ being large primes.
To conduct the proof, we express $k = cd - 1$ as $2^a r$, with $a, r \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r$ being odd.
The algorithm proceeds as follows:

Choose a random $g \in \mathbb{Z}_N^*$.

Check if $\gcd(g, N) \neq 1$. If so, we have found a non-trivial
factor of $N$.

Compute $g^{2^i r} \pmod{N}$ for $i \in \{0, 1, \ldots, a-1\}$.

If for any $i$, $g^{2^i r} \not\equiv \pm1 \pmod{N}$, then we can
factor $N$.


By Fermat's Little Theorem and the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we know that 1 has four roots of unity mod $N$, two of which will reveal non-trivial factors of $N$.
In Boneh, D. (1999), on page 3 (URL: https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf), it is stated that with probability at least $\frac{1}{2}$, one of these computations will reveal the factors of $N$.
My question is:
How can we assume that for a randomly chosen $g$, the roots of unity are evenly distributed? Am I missing something? How do we know that $\pm 1$ isn't much more likely than some $\pm x$ that reveals the factors?
Any Answers, clarifications, questions and comments are very appreciated.
Yours truly, FieldHouser

Do you already believe that they're evenly distributed when the modulus is a prime? If so, the Chinese remainder theorem should allow you to convert that information into an answer to your question.

Thank you for the comment! I didn't know that they are evenly distributed modulo some prime. Is it a simple theorem to prove, or more of an axiomatic idea/theorem  in number theory? - if you know what i mean.

A couple of questions: What do you mean when you say "$1$ has four roots of unity mod $N$"? Almost every element mod $N$ is a root of unity.
Furthermore, what do you mean with the roots of unity being evenly distributed? Do you just mean that for any $g$, the probability of hitting a root of unity when taking powers is the same as any other?

Thank you for the comment i am very happy to clarify
question 1:
I mean that when we take some random $g < N$ with $gcd(g,N)= 1$ and raise it to the power $k$ we get $g^k \equiv 1 (mod N)$ per extension of Fermats little theorem. If we then take $g^{\frac{k}{2}}$ it should be either $\pm 1$ or $\pm x$ where $x \equiv 1 ( mod \ p)$ and $-x \equiv 1 ( mod \ q)$  - 4 roots.

By evenly distributed i mean that are we equally likely to get $\pm x$ and $\pm 1$ when we choose a random $g$?


@SomeCallMeTim From the context I believe the OP is talking specifically about square roots of unity.

@FieldHouser Polynomials modulo a prime can have at most as many roots as their degree, so each of $x^{(p-1)/2}-1$ and $x^{(p-1)/2}-(-1)$ have at most $(p-1)/2$ roots. But every nonzero residue class is a root of one or the other by Fermat's little theorem, so they must have $p-1$ roots in total. We deduce that each one has exactly $(p-1)/2$ roots.

@GregMartin You are totally right it is square roots of unity i need for the proof Thank you. When i take the square root of $g^{k} (mod N)$ then how am i sure that we do not get  $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Maybe my question makes more sense in the context of the content on the bottom of page 3 in the link in the question.

Assume $N=pq$, with $p,q$ primes. Then $(\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z})^\times = (\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^\times \times (\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^\times$. In this setting, we have the four square roots of unity $\pm 1=\pm(1,1),\:\pm x=\pm (1,-1)$.
I think your algorithm is a bit unclear. What I think you mean is the following. Let $g\in (\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z})^\times$.

Compute $g^{a^i r}$ for $i=1,\dots,a$ until you find $i_0$ such that $g^{a^{i_0} r}=1$.

If $g^{a^{i_0-1} r}$ is not $\pm 1$, you have found $\pm x$, and this gives you a factorization of $N$.


The claim is now that the procedure above, for $\text{gcd}(g,N)=1$, finds $\pm x$ with probability at least $\frac12$.
The paper you link claim it is a "straightforward argument", but my proof is slightly complex, unfortunately. Let me provide it anyway.
Let $g=(a,b)\in (\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^\times \times (\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^\times$. It should be clear that $g^{2^i r} = -1$ if and only if $c^{2^i r} = d^{2^i r} =-1$, with the same $i$. In particular, they are both roots in the polynomial $x^{2^i r} -1$ in their respective rings.
Pick $s,t$ such that $p-1=2^e s$ and $q=2^f t$ for some $e,f\geq 1$. Note that $s=\text{gcd}(r,p-1)$, $t=\text{gcd}(r,q-1)$. Then $x^{2^i r}-1$ has at most $2^is$ roots in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ and $2^it$ roots in $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$. This is because the image of $x^{s}$ in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ are just the elements of even multiplicative order, and further taking this image to some odd power simply permutes it. The same story holds for $q$.
Let us wlog assume $e\leq f$. We can now count all the elements $g$ such that $g^{2^i r}= -1$ for some $i$. By the above, we only need to consider $i\leq e-1$, since any higher $i$ will not allow $c^{2^i r} = -1$. Since $c$ and $d$ must both be roots of the same polynomial, in their respective fields, we find an upper bound on the number of elements satisfying $g^{2^i r} = -1$ as $(2^i s)(2^i t)$. Summing over $i$, we get
$$\sum_{i=0}^{e-1} (2^i s)(2^i t) = st\sum_{i=0}^{e-1} 4^i = st \frac{4^e-1}{3} = \frac13(2^e s)(2^e t)-\frac{st}{3} = \frac{1}{3\cdot 2^{f-e}}pq-\frac{st}{3}.$$
One should then compare it to $\frac12\phi(N) = \frac12 pq-\frac12(p+q)$, and one will see that the latter dominates the former (with a little work), thus it is true that less than half the elements in $(\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z})^\times$ hit $-1$ under the procedure above, and thus, more than half find $\pm x$.

Thanks a whole bunch. I am very grateful. Yes, seemingly it is not as straightforward as described, but it makes sense. For the purpose of the proof, the polynomial equivalence is the main point, hence the lack of depth regarding the probability, I guess. In truth, this use of the square roots of unity seems common in modular arithmetic algorithms. Maybe the essence of the proof you did here could be used in the proof of the probability in the Miller-Rabin test, which, in the main cases I have seen, relies on Lagrange's theorem.

You might be right that this strategy can be applied to Miller-Rabin, but I would not want to do so. The truth is that this proof above is already pretty complicated, and very ad hoc, and much neater proofs works for Miller-Rabin, even if it relies on Lagrange. Lagrange's theorem should be very easy to establish in the abelian case, which is all you need.
